# Which version of solidity works web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js

In what version of solidity do I have to write my smart contracts if I want to interact with Web3.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any.

But I suggest not less than >= 0.4.25

If possible, stay on >=0.5.0 for compatibility with current and future Ethereum issue.

Comment: `Use not less than >= 4.25`? Based on what??? Most contract are still at 0.4.24 or even less.

Comment: Do you think is it a good practice to stay on 0.4.24? From my point of view it is included in “any”.

Comment: Solc 0.4.25 fixes one serious bug for certain usages of the `**` operator. If you're using this operator in your contracts, then you're probably better off with Solc 0.4.25. But other than that, at this point, Solc 0.4.24 is probably much more thoroughly tested than any the 0.5.x versions, so it is possibly even better to stay on it than jumping to those (btw, you should add `0.` to your numbers up there).

Comment: In addition to all of the above, Truffle 4 latest version (4.1.14) relies on Solc 0.4.24. And Truffle 5 versions rely on Solc 0.5.x. So if one wishes to stay at Solc 0.4.x, then 0.4.24 seems like a more convenient option.

Comment: Added the zero, thank you, but I do not agree with you. 0.5.0 is the switch from 0.4.26 as a matter of fact and inherits from 0.4.24 and 25 all the minor and major revisions. Pass to 0.5.2 and test your code: this is my point. I do not see any needing to stay on 0.4.24 which have known bugs. ;)

Comment: Btw, we switched to truffle 5.0 without hassle.

Comment: Solc 0.5 introduces breaking changes, meaning that you'd likely need to change your contracts. Truffle 5.x relies on solc 0.5.x, so I'm pretty sure that most people will actually endure a certain amount of hassle.

Comment: I understand that you personally very probably did not switch to 0.5.x yet... we developed using 0.4.24 with pragma experimental 0.5.0 on since early 2018... so we switched immediately with no effort to spend if not something ridiculous here and there. I recommend to stay on the wave and to swim accordingly.

Comment: Anyway I’m afraid these are to be considered “opinions” and are not welcomed here... 

Answer (score 1):

web3js does not introduce any special requirements on the version of solidity you choose to use. In general unless you have specific needs, the recommendation is "use the latest release"